# Test when there are no properties

Tags: php, xml, curl

I've create a script that will delete all user properties for a particular individual. I'm able to use an api call to get the users' properties from the xml. And I'm using a delete api to remove each property.

I would like to be able to test when there are no more properties left and then output a message accordingly. Inside the for loop is where each property is found. Any help is certainly appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
<?php

$user_id="john_smith@ourwiki.com";

$url=('http://user:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/users/=john_smith@ourwiki.com/properties');
$xmlString=file_get_contents($url);

$delete = "http://user:12345@192.168.245.133/@api/DELETE:users/$user_id/properties/%s";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

 function curl_fetch($url,$username,$password,$method='DELETE')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // returns output as a string instead of echoing it
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password"); // if your server requires basic auth do this
    return  curl_exec($ch);
}

foreach($xml->property as $property) {
  $name = $property['name']; // the name is stored in the attribute
  curl_fetch(sprintf($delete, $name),'user','12345');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach` construct automatically loops until the end of the enumerable object (namely `$xml`).

I think you're looking for the [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function:

```
if(!count($xml->property)) die('No more properties');
```